# Is it always sub-optimal to inherit from the class you intend to test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, design-patterns, inheritance, mocking

So, I've been reading Working Effectively With Legacy Code. It's awesome and covers a lot of cool techniques that are also "safe" to use on untested code.

One of my favorite parts about it is the suggestion to extend the class you intend to test when there are troublesome dependencies. For example

```
class FooBar
{
  public List<Foo> ReadFoos()
  {
    var s=new SqlConnection(Config.SomeConntectionStirng);
    s.Read("Foo")....
  }
}
```

gets refactored into

```
class FooBar
{
  public List<Foo> ReadFoos()
  {
    var s=MyConnection();
    s.Read("Foo")....
  }
  protected virtual IConnection MyConnection()
  {
    return new SqlConnection(Config.SomeConnectionString);   
  }
}
```

And then to test it, you'd inherit from it like so:

```
class TestableFooBar : FooBar
{
  protected override IConnection MyConnection()
  {
    return new MockConnection();
  }
}
```

and test upon the extended class.

Now, my question. Is this OK to do and not refactor later? The main reason I say this is because this could be useful for some code that is generally difficult to unit test without making the calling API harder to use. On a public API, you definitely want it to be as simple as possible. So, is this an OK thing to keep by-design?

Comment: Any reason you're not using dependency injection?  This is essentially its raison d'etre.

Comment: @KirkWoll, based on the book he is reading and his question text, he is trying to move from presumably horrible, untestable legacy code to something cleaner. It's typically a process accomplished in many, many small increments.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram, ah, good point.  Ignored the subject of the book he was citing.

Comment: @KirkWoll am I the only one that doesn't like putting yet another framework in my framework? :)

Answer (score 5):

From a design standpoint, "extract and override" is probably not where you would *choose* to finish, but it comes down to your budget for changing existing code that works versus adding new features. While you also might not be keen on changing the public API, there are techniques to preserve the API while also allowing more proper dependency injection. I believe the book discusses one such technique, which is a default constructor that provides the dependency to an overload (sample below), and another can be simply using a dependency injection container.

```
public class Foo
{
     IDependency dependency;

     public Foo() // preserves API
          : this(new Dependency())
     {
     }

     internal Foo(IDependency dependency) 
     {
         this.dependency = dependency;
     }
```

Note: In this sample, I have marked the second constructor as internal, but you could leave it as public, particularly if you would like classes outside your assembly to have the option of providing that dependency. For simple testability, I like the internal modifier, because I would expose the internals to my unit testing project(s) via the "InternalsVisibleTo" assembly attribute. This allows you to keep your API clean, but also have maximum testability for techniques such as this, but also internal helper classes.